# How can I update a trial merge branch in git?

Tags: git

Joe wants to make a change to my project.  He submits a PR of his branch called `new_feature`.  It's big, so I want to do a trial merge and exercise the code.  So I do:

```
git remote add joe https://github.com/joe/project/
git fetch joe
git checkout -b trial_merge
git merge joe/new_feature
```

So far so good.  But if I find a bug and send it back to Joe, how to I update my `trial_merge` branch once he has changed his `new_feature` branch?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/wavexx/git-assembler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw the first merge away and do the merge again. Here, I assume that you did not make a commit after the first merge; if you did, count back to before the merge and use that number instead of 1.

```
git switch trial_merge
git reset --hard @~1 
git fetch joe
git merge joe/new_feature
```

Comment: This is at least a bit shorter than what I was doing, which was deleting the whole branch and starting again.  I guess there's no way to just pull and integrate the latest of joe's new_feature branch?

Comment: A pull is a merge. Do you really want to merge Joe with the previous merge of Joe? That would be a pretty unhelpful test. So I'm saying, erase the previous merge first.